# Template definitions outside class body

Tags: c++, templates, virtual, inline

Is it O.K. to define virtual function of class template outside its body? Virtual function can not be inlined, but to avoid multiple definitions in compilation units they shall be marked `inline` (assuming that template headers will be included in multiple source files). On the other hand compiler is free to ignore `inline`, so this seems valid. By an example, is the code below correct:

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
public:
    virtual void f(T val);
};

template <typename T>
inline
void C<T>::f(T val)
{
  //definition
}
```

?

BTW gcc (3.4.2) allows to omit `inline` before definition of function `f(T val)` but not before analogous function of regular class. Is it only gcc's behaviour?

Comment: @jpalecek in this particular example, yes.

Comment: @doc - Virtual functions *can* be declared `inline` (but that is not needed here). The compiler just has a bit harder to figure out exactly when the functions can be inlined.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it's OK even without `inline`. It works the same for ordinary member functions and static variables:

```
// everything in the header:
template <class T>
class A
{
  static int i;
};

template <class T>
int A<T>::i=0;
```

Standard quote: (3.2/5)

> There can be more than one deﬁnition of a class type (Clause 9), enumeration type (7.2), inline function with
>   external linkage (7.1.2), class template (Clause 14), non-static function template (14.5.6), static data member
>   of a class template (14.5.1.3), **member function of a class template** (14.5.1.1), or template specialization for
>   which some template parameters are not speciﬁed (14.7, 14.5.5) in a program provided that each deﬁnition
>   appears in a diﬀerent translation unit, and provided the deﬁnitions satisfy the following requirements ...

The requirements basically say the two definitions have to be identical.

It doesn't work in case of regular classes. There has to be at most one definition in the whole program.

Answer (score 10):

You can define template methods outside the `class` definition, in the same header, without using `inline` and without receiving multiple definition errors.

**That's because a template function doesn't generate a definition itself, if it's not fully specialized**. To prove my point, the following:

```
void C<int>::f(int)
{
}
```

will result in a linker error, as the function has a definition in this case. (provided you include this in multiple translation units. If you mark it inline:

```
inline void C<int>::f(int)
{
}
```

the error no longer occurs.

Answer (score 4):

You can define the functions there, as long as any code which needs to instantiate the function in question has visibility of that code at compile time (not link time).

It's quite common to separate a template into 2 files, one being a traditional header, and the second being the implementation, as with non-templated functions and their implementation. The only difference is that you need to #include the template implementation file as well as the header when you want to use it.