# How to correctly use templates accross a multi-file project?

Tags: c++, templates, header-files

I have been learning about templates in C++ and they seem very handy. However, there was a note about the problems using templates in a large, multi-file project in http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/ at the very bottom: "Because templates are compiled when required, this forces a restriction for multi-file projects: the implementation (definition) of a template class or function must be in the same file as its declaration."

So take for example, wanting to write a 2D Vector class template which operates on `T` typename:

```
    template <class T>
    class Vector {
        T x, y;
    public:
        Vector(T x, T y)
        {
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
        }

        void normalize()
        {
            T length = sqrt(x * x + y * y);

            x = x / length;
            y = y / length;
        }
    };
```

My question is rather simple, where would you put this template so that multiple .cpp files have access to it? If you put it inside of, say, a Math.h file where you keep all of your other custom math related declarations, do you have to `inline` the functions because they are in a header file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put them in a Math.h file as you suggest. Wherever needed, you will `#include "Math.h"` and then instantiate the template as necessary.

You need not inline functions that are defined **inside** class definitions, even in a `.h` file. So in the following code, nothing is explicitly inlined:

```
template <class T>
class Vector {
    T x, y;
public:
    Vector(T x, T y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }

    void normalize()  //no need to inline (in fact, it's automatically inlined for you)
    {
        T length = sqrt(x * x + y * y);

        x = x / length;
        y = y / length;
    }

    T GetX();
};


template<class T> Vector<T>::GetX() {  //outside class definition, also need not be inlined
  return x;
}
```

Note: If Vector were a non-templated class, the GetX function *would* need to be inlined. Among other things, member functions of **template classes** need not be inlined.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211273/template-definitions-outside-class-body) for more info.

Of course, you can put your `Vector` class code in a `Vector.h` file, and include that file in `Math.h`. Same rules about inlining apply. And then `#include "Math.h"` or `#include "Vector.h"` will both get you access to your Vector class template.