# Do templated ctor and methods need "inline" specifier if defined outside class?

Tags: c++, class, templates, inline

As templates need to be defined in header files so the compiler can instantiate them I find myself hiding my implemention details in a *.tcc file at the end of the "main" header. Which means the implementation details will be included by any module that includes my header.

So I would need them to be inline to avoid odr-violations. Now I know that in-class definition of class methods automatically makes them inline. Does that mean that if I define them outside of the class I still need to manually add the specifier? Also I found [this IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=only-inline-member-functions-c) that says I might as well specify the in-class declarations inline which would also implicitely make the definitions inline:

> An equivalent way to declare an inline member function is to either
> declare it in the class with the inline keyword (and define the
> function outside of its class) or to define it outside of the class
> declaration using the inline keyword.

Is that correct?

```
/* myheader.hpp */

#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class myclass
{
    myclass(T);

    auto print() -> void;

    T val_;
};

#inlcude "myheader.tcc"


/* myheader.tcc */

template <typename T>
/* inline? */ myclass<T>::myclass(T val)
    :   val_{ std::move(val) }
{ }

template <typename T>
/* inline? */ auto myclass<T>::print() -> void
{
    printf("There are 10 types of people in this world, those who understand binary and those who dont!\n");
}
```

Comment: somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535667/does-it-make-any-sense-to-use-inline-keyword-with-templates. unfortunately answers do not mention members of class templates

Comment: more related https://stackoverflow.com/q/10211273/4117728

Comment: hm... second could make a good duplicate, see eg this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10211357/4117728

Comment: yes. dupe, accepted has the relevant quote from the standard

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number But doesn't that mean that if I include a header file with templates from multiple places and I instantiate the same template (same template parameters) it will exist in two translation units at the same time and violate odr-rules?

Comment: see the quote in the accepted answer. They are implicitly inline and do not violate odr

Comment: "There can be more than one deﬁnition [.....] provided that each deﬁnition appears in a diﬀerent translation unit, and provided the deﬁnitions satisfy the following requirements ..."

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number They are not implicitly `inline`, although being a templated entity comes with the same ODR effect as `inline`. Technically declaring it `inline` in one translation unit and not `inline` in another would still be  IFNDR.